# Value Aggregation along Traversal Gremlin Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, traversal, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I need to perform a query of the following form: I have a tree structure with costs at the leaf node. I need a single query to give me all the aggregated costs under the root node. 
[image]

For example in the above graph, I would expect an output from my query like

```
{ 1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 1}
```

I was looking into using the 'sack' step from the Gremlin API for this, but cosmosDB doesn't seem to support sacks currently. I also tried storing a pseudo-property of "aggregated-cost" and working my way up from the leaf nodes, but I was unable to figure out how to store a dynamic value at each node as a property that is local to only that node. 
Is this kind of query possible given these constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking questions about Gremlin, it is always best to include a short Gremlin script of sample data:

```
g.addV().property('id',1).as('1').
  addV().property('id',2).as('2').
  addV().property('id',3).as('3').
  addV().property('id',4).property('cost',1).as('4').
  addV().property('id',5).property('cost',1).as('5').
  addV().property('id',6).property('cost',2).as('6').
  addV().property('id',7).property('cost',1).as('7').
  addV().property('id',8).property('cost',1).as('8').
  addE('link').from('1').to('2').
  addE('link').from('1').to('3').
  addE('link').from('2').to('4').
  addE('link').from('2').to('5').
  addE('link').from('2').to('6').
  addE('link').from('3').to('7').
  addE('link').from('3').to('8').iterate()
```

With the steps available in CosmosDB I think that the closest you might be able to get is this:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   group().
......2>     by('id').
......3>     by(emit(has('cost')).
......4>        repeat(out()).
......5>        values('cost').
......6>        fold())
==>[1:[1,1,2,1,1],2:[1,1,2],3:[1,1],4:[1],5:[1],6:[2],7:[1],8:[1]]
```

The `group()` helps produce the `Map` structure you wanted. Then for each vertex you group on you use `repeat()` to traverse out until you reach the leaf vertices. Note that `emit()` is ensuring that only those vertices that are leaves with the "cost" property are being returned for purpose of the result.

The reason I say that this is about as close as you can get with CosmosDB is because I don't see that CosmosDB supports the `sum()` step [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support). If it did then:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   group().
......2>     by('id').
......3>     by(emit(has('cost')).
......4>        repeat(out()).
......5>        values('cost').
......6>        sum())
==>[1:6,2:4,3:2,4:1,5:1,6:2,7:1,8:1]
```

I guess you will have to do that final computation on the returned result yourself.

For others (or when CosmosDB supports `sack()` in the future) you can do:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('cost').
......1>   sack(assign).
......2>     by('cost').
......3>   emit().
......4>     repeat(__.in('link')).
......5>   group().
......6>     by('id').
......7>     by(sack().sum())
==>[1:6,2:4,3:2,4:1,5:1,6:2,7:1,8:1]
```

Courtesy of the [Gremlin Guru](http://gremlin.guru).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Once cosmos releases support for sacks, would there be a way to do it using those? Because (correct me if I'm wrong), the current way repeats a lot of computation with repeat(out()) at each node?

Comment: Also, just an fyi for anyone who sees this later, cosmosDB does support sum!